# The argument type 'XFile' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uint8List'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-image-picker

I try to upload an image to firebase storage:

First: Pick an image as XFile using image_picker: ^0.8.6 package.
Second: use UploadTask method to upload the XFile to the storage.
But I got (The argument type 'XFile' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uint8List') error.

How can I convert the Xfile into Unit8List?
or any kind of solution?

I have searched for a solution But I didn't find any that works for me.

Comment: can you include sample code-snippet that will reproduce the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/cross_file/latest/cross_file/XFile-class.html):

```dart
XFile? file = await picker.pickImage(...);
Uint8List? bytes = await file?.readAsBytes();
```